# Ruby: Array manipulation

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
test = Array.new
test[0] = "foo"
```

works fine

```
test[] = "foo"
```

returns an error. What's the Ruby syntax to have an array automatically generate its index?

Comment: [See the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html)

Comment: For future reference, we welcome any valid programming question, provided that you've [done your research](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This format:

```
test << "foo"
```

will append an element to an array as you're describing.

Answer (score 5):

```
test << "foo"
```

or

```
test.push("foo").
```